# Ajax add more implementation of several buttons - undefined index problem

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I want to set a custom form with multiple "add more" buttons in Drupal 7. For now I'm trying with 2, but it doesn't work, I get: "Notice: Undefined index: main_film_tab in custom_registration_ajax_button_add_country_callback()".

I think my loops are not working or getting mixed up, because it works for the first button but not for the second.

I've read that I should assign a #name property for the ajax button, but I can't find information on how to do it properly. I've seen some implementations using $delta, but since my button is not in the loop it wouldn't work here.

Many thanks!!!

Here's my form:

```php
function main_form_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form = array();

    //** Horizontal Tabs Container
  $form['group_tabs'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'horizontal_tabs',
    '#attached' => array('library' => array(array('field_group', 'horizontal-tabs'))), // Converts fieldsets into tabs
  );

    // Main Film tab
  $form['main_film_tab'] = array(
    '#type'  => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Film General Info'),
    '#description' => t('Use this tab to enter basic info about the film.'),
    '#group' => 'group_tabs',
  );

  $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_title'] =
  isset($form_state['main_film_tab']['add_title']) ?    $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_title'] : 0;

  $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_country'] =
  isset($form_state['main_film_tab']['add_country']) ? $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_country'] : 0;

  $form['main_film_tab']['film_title']= array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Film Title'),
    '#size' => 60,
    '#maxlength' => 120,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#group' => 'main_film_tab',
    '#description' => t('Enter Film Title.'),
    '#attributes' => array(
      'title' => t("Title of Film"),
    )
  );

  $form['main_film_tab']['add_title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#group' => 'main_film_tab',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="add-title">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  if ($form_state['main_film_tab']['add_title']) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_title']; $i++) {
      if ($i <= 2) {
        $form['main_film_tab']['add_title'][$i] = array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#tree' => TRUE,
        );

        $form['main_film_tab']['add_title'][$i]['main_film_tab']['film_title_'.$i] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Film Title '.$i),
          '#size' => 60,
          '#maxlength' => 120,
          '#required' => FALSE,
          '#group' => 'main_film_tab',
          '#description' => t('Enter Film Title.'),
          '#attributes' => array(
            'title' => t("Title of Film"),
          )
        );
      }
      else {
        return FALSE; 
      }
    }
  }

  $form['main_film_tab']['button_add_title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add another title.'),
    '#href' => '',
    '#submit' => 'custom_registration_ajax_button_add_title_submit',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'custom_registration_ajax_button_add_title',
      'wrapper' => 'add-title',
    ),
  );

  $form['main_film_tab']['button_add_title']['#executes_submit_callback'] = FALSE;
  $form['main_film_tab']['button_add_title']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array();

  $form['main_film_tab']['film_country'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Film Country'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => country_get_list(),                                                                                  
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#empty_value' => '- Select -',
    '#group' => 'main_film_tab',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'title' => t("Select country from list."),
    )
  );

  $form['main_film_tab']['add_country'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#group' => 'main_film_tab',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="add-country">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  if ($form_state['main_film_tab']['add_country']) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_country']; $j++) {
      if ($j <= 2) {
        $form['main_film_tab']['add_country'][$j] = array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#tree' => TRUE,
        );

        $form['main_film_tab']['add_country'][$j]['main_film_tab']['film_country_'.$j] = array(
          '#title' => t('Film Country '.$j),
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#options' => country_get_list(),                                                                                  
          '#required' => FALSE,
          '#empty_value' => '- Select -',
          '#group' => 'main_film_tab',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'title' => t("Select country from list."),
          )
        );
      }
      else {
        return FALSE; 
      }
    }
  }

  $form['main_film_tab']['button_add_country'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add another country.'),
    '#submit' => 'custom_registration_ajax_button_add_country_submit',
    '#href' => '',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'custom_registration_ajax_button_add_country',
      'wrapper' => 'add-country',
    ),
  );

  $form['main_film_tab']['button_add_country']['#executes_submit_callback'] = FALSE;
  $form['main_film_tab']['button_add_country']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array(); 

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save Film Info'),
  );

  $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_title']++;
  $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_country']++;


  return $form;

}
```

And the callback functions:

```php
function custom_registration_ajax_button_add_title_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_title']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function custom_registration_ajax_button_add_title_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['main_film_tab']['add_title'];
}

function custom_registration_ajax_button_add_country_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['main_film_tab']['add_country']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function custom_registration_ajax_button_add_country_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['main_film_tab']['add_country'];
}
```